# Want to create new text channel with discord bot button

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I want to create a discord bot that is able to create a new private text channel between the person who clicked the button and our mods of the server. I can't figure out how to get the button to recognize the interaction.

Currently, the code below gets returns this in the terminal when I click the button:

```
> await interaction.guild.create_text_channel("Bot-made channel", category="brendan")
> AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'guild'

with "interaction.guild" underlined
```

```py
import discord
from discord.ui import Button, View
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
from discord import Permissions
from discord.utils import get

guild = serverID
vanguard = roleID

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=Intents.all())

class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="Create new private channel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def menu1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.guild.create_text_channel("Bot-made channel", category="general")

@bot.command()
async def menu(ctx):
    view = MyView()
    await ctx.reply(view=view)

bot.run('MyToken')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They swapped the item position and interaction position in the callbacks. So you can just swap their position.

**From**

```py
async def menu1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ...
```

**To**

```py
async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    ...
```

Comment: So I did this and get given an Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @Brendan the docs say that the `category` argument should be a `CategoryChannel` instance, not a string... https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel